# file transferring via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I would like to develop an iOS application that send files between other devices over bluetooth. The app should be able to recieve data from other (non)iOS devices and save it locally.

My question: Is this possible and allowed by Apple, and if so: Where can I find a good tutorial about this? The only things I find using google are on jailbroken phones, which is not something I am looking for.